# Insert an image inside the <a> tag of wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a menu in WordPress that has an image above the link and the text below the link.

I would like it to be dynamic and using the built-in WordPress menu function. I see so many hacks stating use CSS to make it a background image yet that doesn't make the image clickable.

Is there a way to get WordPress to add an `<img>`- or `<span>`-tag inside the `<a>`-tag?

Comment: The image would be clickable as a background if you made it a background of the `<a>` tag, which you changed to `display: block` and added padding to push the text out of the space the image will occupy. Still a hack, but possible and clickable.

Comment: Using CSS to add a background is not a hack at all.  It's much better than actually having an image nested in every link.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items/26079191

Answer (score 3):

Try using the 'link_before' or 'link_after' options to wp_nav_menu.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'link_before' => '<img src="myImage.jpg" />'
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args); 
?>
```

This will insert something either before or after the link text of the menu item.