# Add PHP Code In Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

i am trying to add a php code in wordpress menu. Here is the code in header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-nav', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'fallback_cb' => 'null')); ?>
```

I want to add this code near fourth menu item.

```
<?php my_bp_adminbar_notifications_menu()?>
```

Comment: You can achieve this using this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items/26079191

Comment: i tried that but i couldnt. Sorry for that but i am not good on php :(