# wordpress custom menu with page thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to get a menu with few links, and show their/link/page featured image. following is my code for functions.php.

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ),
      'useful-links' => __( 'Userful Links' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

and this is where i am calling it in the page.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'useful-links', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'useful-links', 'menu'=>'Posts Menu' ) ); ?>
```

i know something is missing but kindly advice. my page look and feel allow 6 links and their images.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be in your functions.php to register the menu within WordPress.

```
if (!function_exists('wp_basicTemplateSetup')) {
    function wp_basicTemplateSetup() {
        // Register the Main Menus into WordPress
        register_nav_menus(array(
            'primary' => __('Main Menu', 'theme-name'),
        ));
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wp_basicTemplateSetup');
```

In your theme, where the menu is sitting you need to tell the menu function, which menu to look for. So..:

```
// Variable that tells WordPress which menu to use, look at "Theme Location"
// Put this variable either at the top of your theme, of right *before* the  function wp_nav_menu

$mainmenu = array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'some-menu-css-class',
    'depth' => 2
);

// The WordPress menu function
<?php wp_nav_menu($mainmenu); ?>
```

These 3 components are necessary to get your WordPress menu working.

Comment: useful links is performing the first component. i am able to call my menu at specific location of the theme. only want to call image of anchor which is the image of post. hope you understood.

Comment: ahh nope - sorry - If you want to get an image of a post (It may be your first link or whatever.. then you need to query WordPress for the post, not the menu.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items

Comment: any idea above link